# How can I make this to a loop?

Tags: javascript

How can I make this to a loop? the array tabProsent contains 70 numbers.

```
var startVerdi=1000;

 if(slider.value==tab[0]){
    output2.innerHTML = startVerdi*tabProsent[0];
  }

  if(slider.value==tab[1]){
    output2.innerHTML = startVerdi*tabProsent[0]*tabProsent[1];
  }

  if(slider.value==tab[2]){
    output2.innerHTML = startVerdi*tabProsent[0]*tabProsent[1]*tabProsent[2];
  }

  if(slider.value==tab[3]){
    output2.innerHTML = startVerdi*tabProsent[0]*tabProsent[1]*tabProsent[2]*tabProsent[3];
}
```

Comment: What's the max value of the tab ? Can you explain what's the differents arrays are with initial values?

Comment: the tab contains integer numbers from 1950 to 2020. its suppose to be a year tab

Comment: tabProsent array contains many different double numbers between 1.0 and 1.13.

Comment: both arrays contains equal amount of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the array methods [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var startVerdi=1000;
var index = tab.indexOf(slider.value);

if (index !== -1) {
  output2.innerHTML = tabProsent.slice(0, index + 1).reduce(
    (acc, cur) => acc * cur, startVerdi
  );
}
```

Comment: I like this answer nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this -

```js
var startVerdi=1000;

for(let i=0;i<70;i++){        // check for tab[0], tab[1] and so on...
  if(slider.value == tab[i]){
    let temp = startVerdi;
    for(let j=0;j<=i;j++){
      temp = temp * tabProsent[j]  // multiply with tabProsent[0], tabProsent[1] and so on...
    }
    output2.innerHTML = temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and understandable method : you need two loops:

- One to find the index of **tab** that corresponds to the slider value
- Another (inner loop) to create the product of values of **tabProsent** that are smaller or equal to the index of **tab**:

```html
const MAX_TAB_IDX = 69; // 0 to 69 gives 70 values
let startVerdi=1000;

for(let idx=0; idx<=MAX_TAB_IDX; idx++) { // First loop

    if(slider.value == tab[idx]) { // We found it!! Lets calculate the product..

        let product=1;
        for(let subidx=0; subidx <= idx; subidx ++) // Second loop
            product *= tabProsent[subidx];

        output2.innerHTML = startVerdi * product;
        
        break; // This is to stop the loop!
    }
}
```

There are other more elegant ways (for example, using slice and map functions) - this is so you can understand how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments under the question and answer from Patrick Roberts, here is working example:

```js
// Prepare data:
var startVerdi = 1000;
let tabProsent = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 70; i++) tabProsent.push(Math.random() * 0.13 + 1);

function sliderChanged(val) {
  const index = val - 1950;
  const total = tabProsent.slice(0, index + 1).reduce(
    (acc, cur) => acc * cur, startVerdi
  );
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1950" max="2020" onchange="sliderChanged(this.value)" oninput="sliderChanged(this.value)" />

<label id="result">?</label>
```